# Backing Gmail stops after a few Gb's

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007

So far, I've been using Gmail through their web interface exclusivly. Then, since I often work without a network connection, I decided to get it all into outlook (v2007), so I can access it offline. I knew I could've used Gmail's offline package, but I prefer outlook, as it being a "normal application", and I'm used to it more than to these "new applications".

Okey, so I set up my settings in Gmail, setup my servers in outlook, login and pass, and left it to download it all. My complete mail was at 6,3 Gb. He finished, and at first glance everythign was ok, so I didn't pay much attention.

Then, just today I discover that he downloaded only about 2 Gb's of mail. The rest is missing. I've tried it again, setting a new outlook file (.psd) and restarting the whole process. Again, the same thing.

Has anyone noticed this behaviour before, and what could be the source of the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect Gmail throttles requests to manage automated bulk accesses as all sites do.

If you are continuing from a 2GB download made earlier,
you should see the remaining download continuing.
If you retry the entire download, the throttle should hit again at about the same place.

Answer (score 0):

What OS is the computer that is running Outlook? Oh - and what version of Outlook? Seems like I recall that older Outlook versions had a max PST file size of 2GB.

Comment: Oh bosh. I just noticed your "outlook-2007" tag. I guess you can ignore my response -- unless your drive is formatted FAT16 :-)

Comment: It is running on XPsp2, with FAT32. The first time it downloaded 2,2 Gb; the second time about 2,33Gb. Why the difference (curious) ? As far as outlook versions comment goes, I never had problems reaching 4Gb's of file sizes (after which I'd usually back it up on a dvd, that being the limit of the disk; having it on disk usually slowed outlook to no end).